# gnu parallel: sync output?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, synchronization, gnu-parallel

I am running a gnu parallel job like this:

```
parallel program ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 > output.txt
```

I want to guarantee that the output file is ordered. That is, the first lines corresponds to the output of `program 1`, the next lines to the output of `program 2`, etc.

How can I guarantee this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `-k` option might be what you want:

> ```
>  --keep-order
>    -k       Keep sequence of output same as the order of input.
>             Normally the output of a job will be printed as soon
>             as the job completes.
>             Try this to see the difference:
>               parallel -j4 sleep {}\; echo {} ::: 2 1 4 3
>               parallel -j4 -k sleep {}\; echo {} ::: 2 1 4 3
> ```

In the former example from the man page, the output is `1 2 3 4`, while the latter indeed produces `2 1 4 3`.